# Php - Codeigniter url spaces

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I'm trying to do is when i clicked my specific product, instead of the id of my product would appear in my url, i want to put the name of the product . 
what i did today is base_url/controller/method/id

i want to do is base_url/controller/method/product-name or base_url/controller/method/product_name

but in my code what happened is in my product name all the spaces is occupied by %20 what should i do to replace the %20 by either underscore or dash or whatever safe way to call the product name in url.

and whatever i get on that $name(product_name) i will pass it to my model.

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function details($name){


    $prod_row = $this->PromoModel->getpromorow($name);
    $data['promodetail'] = $prod_row;

    $data['promo'] = $this->PromoModel->get_promo();

    $data['message']= "<h1> NO PROMOS AVAILABLE</h1>";
    $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/nav');
    $this->load->view('promo/PromoDetail', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

**MY MODEL**

```
public function getpromorow($name) {
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $query = $this->db->get('promo');
    return $query->row();
}

public function get_promo(){
    $query = $this->db->get('promo');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**MY VIEW**

```
<a href="<?= base_url(). 'promos/details/' . $promo_row->name ?>"> </a>
```

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '_', $promo_row->name)` OR `str_replace(' ', '-', $promo_row->name)`, do this before putting it in the url.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix give best idea for you and also you can use `urlencode()` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
  <a href="<?= base_url(). 'promos/details/' . str_replace(' ', '_', $promo_row->name); ?>"> </a>
```

As far as `-` vs `_` if you are routing to them, for example say that product name becomes a method in your controller, I don't think PHP allows `-` in method names, but it doesn't allow spaces either..  You can cheat using `__call()` but that's a other story for a different day.

If its a parameter, then it shouldn't matter as much. Just if it is a method/function name.

-Note- this is not a CI specific error, look at any url, tell me if you see spaces in them.

**UPdate:**  as a suggestion the best way to handle this is by having a field dedicated to the url name ( such as `slug` or such ) and when a new product is made just do the transform on the name.  Then it's an editable piece of data you have control over.  For example what if you have a product with a `-` in it's name.  This will probably cause issues.  You can avoid that by having a separate piece of data just for that, it could even be like a SKU number etc.  It's more work to setup, but in the long run more maintainable.

Comment: i tried the code you post and it works, and when it comes to the controller, i did it vice versa $url = str_replace(' -',  ' ', $name); then i decode it to $decode = urldecode($url) and pass it to may model $prod_row = $this->PromoModel->getpromorow($decode); so i can pass the exact name in my model which i will get all the info of that specific product. i don't know if that's the right or safe way or if you have any suggestion for that. but thank you for helping me.

Comment: It's probably better to remove the spaces in the link itself, because you are relying on the behavior of the browser, by leaving them in.  If I understand that ^ correctly.  You can always remove them after the fact using `str_replace('-', ' ', $product )` just make sure not to put the `-` in the product name.

Comment: Another, even better way is to add a field in to the products, named `slug` and use that field for the url name, you can have it automatically created when adding a new product but because it's editable you have more control over it.

Comment: noted! and i just notice that in my comment its str_replace('-' , ' ', $name) but in my code its not dash its underscore so that's minor correction. but thank you for that suggestion and ill place it in my notes.

Comment: Sure thing glad I could help.  I would really recommend making a separate field in the product,  I don't know if you built all the product stuff yourself or not.  But for the control it gives you I would be worth the work.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. But best would be to use `urldecode($value)`. Since "%" from "%20" gets encoded again to "%25", we might have to use `urldecode` twice. In this case - `urldecode(urldecode($promo_row->name))`